# How do I left, right, center align String in Java?

Tags: java, string, console, width, text-alignment

[Console Library Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt7Xk.png)

I need to make a neat looking box and make the String to be in left, right, or center alignment. I have made the text to be in the center already, but I could print blankSize in front of the text only, not after the text. Therefore, the box is broken on the right side of the text shown as the picture above. How do I fix this?

Thank you!

```
public static int width = 80;
public static int height = 25;
public static int left = 1;
public static int center = 2;
public static int right = 3;

/*
Outputs 25 empty lines.
 */
public static void clearScreen() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void printBlankLine() {
    System.out.print('│');
    for (int i = 0; i < width - 2; i++) {
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println('│');
}

public static void printMessage(String message, int alignment) {
    System.out.print("│ ");
    int blankSize = 0;
    if (alignment == 2) {
        blankSize = (width - (2 + message.length() + 2)) / 2;
    }else if (alignment == 3) {
        blankSize = (width - (2 + message.length() + 2));
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < blankSize ; i++) {
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.print(message);
    System.out.println(" │");
}

public static void showMainMenu() {
    clearScreen();

    // prints the top line
    System.out.print('┌');    // top-left
    for (int i = 0; i < width - 2; i++) {
        System.out.print('─');
    }
    System.out.println('┐');    // top-right

    printMessage("Welcome to LCD Library Demo", 2);    // center
    printBlankLine();
    printMessage("Select a Function (1-3)", 2);

    // prints the middle line
    System.out.print('├');  // middle-left
    for (int i = 0; i < width - 2; i++) {
        System.out.print('─');
    }
    System.out.println('┤');    // middle-right

    printBlankLine();
    printMessage("1. Login", 1);    // left
    printMessage("2. Restart", 1);
    printMessage("3. Shutdown", 1);

    // prints the bottom line
    System.out.print('└');  // bottom-left
    for (int i = 0; i < width - 2; i++) {
        System.out.print('─');
    }
    System.out.println('┘');    // bottom-right
}
```

Comment: Thx! I made it work. Then now here's the problem... When the String characters are odd, the box is broken. Is there any way to fix it without changing the method?

Comment: That should not be a problem. You know the size of the box. Subtract the size of the string. Integer-divide by two. That is your space to fill before the string. Subtract that and the size of the string from the size of the box. That is the space to fill after the string.